# Horizontal and vertical centering of mdframed image on page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, mdframed, includegraphics

I would like to place one large image into the horizontal and vertical center of each page in a multi-page document and simultaneously have each image placed into a thin, black frame. Each image shall be oversized somewhat with regard to the mdframe such that the frame over-prints the image.

Why is the following code failing on all three counts (horizontal alignment, vertical alignment, and frame)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}

\vfill
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=1pt, leftmargin=0cm, rightmargin=0cm, align=left]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{mdframed}
\vfill
\pagebreak

\vfill
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=1pt, align=center]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{mdframed}
\vfill
\pagebreak

\vfill
\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=1pt, align=right]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{mdframed}
\vfill

\end{document}
```

*Edit 1:*
Desired outcome with regard to image and frame:
[image]

Comment: `\centering` will not center an over-full box, over full boxes always overflow on the right, but it isn't clear what you want the mdframed to do, why not simply `\fbox` or `\frame` ?  you are specifying alignment in the options then over-riding that with `\centering` and then adding over-sized content?  You could use negative space but then the image would over-print the rule to the left and under-print the rule to the right?

Comment: white space is discarded at a page break so you want `\vspace*{\fill}` just as horizontal space is dropped at a line break unless you use `\hspace*`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My goal is to have an image that overprints the mdframe equally on all four sides.

Comment: I guess my answer is not what you want then as I guessed wrong, but I don't understand, if you draw a frame and then over-print it, that is the same as not drawing it at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "Overprint" may not the correct term. My goal is to have an image that exceeds the frame equally on all four sides while the black frame is still visible.

Comment: that would be the frame over-printing the image., so not like my answer where the frame fitted the image, but the frame+image runs in to the page margin, your description doesn't match that though, it says you want the frame to fit the image "tight" which is what I did, not that the frame should be a fixed size and the image exceed that space?  can you add an image showing the desired outcome (just fake the output in a drawing/ image editor)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited the initial question to make my goal clearer.

Comment: I updated answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Spot on! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question as to why the code in the question did not work,

Vertical centering is not achieved because space is discarded at the top of a page, just as inter-word space is dropped at al linebreak, so you want `\vspace*{\fill}` not `\vfill` where the `*` form  prevents the space being dropped.

The frame is not tight to the image as essentially you are wrapping a parbox of width `\textwidth` so the frame is around that. The image makes the box over-full but that does not change the frame size.

Horizontal centering is not achieved as `\centering` does not center over-full boxes, the overflow is always on the right.

---

I'm not sure I understood the requirements but perhaps

---

**plan B**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\centering

\linethickness{2pt}

\vspace*{\fill}

\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=1.25\textwidth,trim=10pt 10pt 10pt 10pt]{example-image}}

\makebox[0pt]{\usebox{0}\llap{\frame{\phantom{\usebox0}}}}

\vspace*{\fill}


\end{document}
```

---

**plan A**

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\centering

\vspace*{\fill}

\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\frame{\includegraphics[width=1.25\textwidth]{example-image}}}

\vspace*{\fill}

\pagebreak

\vspace*{\fill}

\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\frame{\includegraphics[width=1.25\textwidth]{example-image}}}

\vspace*{\fill}

\pagebreak

\vspace*{\fill}

\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\frame{\includegraphics[width=1.25\textwidth]{example-image}}}

\vspace*{\fill}



\end{document}
```